# Attribute becomes null shortly after it is set

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

In my program, I have a controller that, based on user requests, creates new Forms and new objects that will be used by those forms. To put it simply, this:

```
ClientForm clientForm = new ClientForm();
Client client = new Client();
clientForm.SetClient( client );
clientForm.Show();
```

`SetClient` does something obvious:

```
Client _client;

public ClientForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public void SetClient( Client client )
{
    this._client = client;
}
```

If I try to use `_client` while I'm in `SetClient` everything works fine, but if I try to use it from an event handler I get a `NullReferenceException` and, indeed, a simple if check reveals that `_client` is `null`.

Why is this happening? Is it going out of scope or something? How can I prevent that?

Comment: There isn't much code left as I discovered this in a test run (create a form, send it a new Client, call ToString() when a button is pressed). If I try calling this.client.ToString() in SetClient there are no problems.

Comment: where are you running the first piece of code? is it in main() function? or in some form.. and where is your event handler being handled and what is the handler's code.. please provide more details

Comment: I wanted to edit with extra code and when I re-read all the code I wanted to add I noticed a new ClientForm() where there should have been no new. Now I feel stupid.

Comment: :) don't worry, happens to everyone.

Comment: @user3002428: you can answer your own question on this site, so it will be clear what the solution was.

Comment: @siride there wasn't really a solution. Just an extra new. I guess it could do no harm if I add an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm posting an answer just so the question won't stay without one.

I usually don't like copy-pasting code here because I'm not coming here to ask others to read my code and find syntax errors / typos etc - or at least I try.

So I stripped my code of all of the extra and made sure the bug reproduced with the simple version. Then I re-read it to make sure it looks nice and easy to read and I saw it.

I had some things going on in Main because this was a program made in order to test some ideas.

```
static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault( false );

            LauncherForm launcher = new LauncherForm();
            Client client = new Client( "test" );

            launcher.SetClient( client );

            Application.Run( new LauncherForm() );

        }
    }
```

And here it was, starring me in the eyes: `Application.Run( new LauncherForm() );` should have been `Application.Run( launcher );`

This would have been observable with the `.GetHashCode` solution that someone suggested in the comments (solution I'm sure I'm going to use from now on when things like this happen, so thank you). My simple approach (see how `_client` is in `SetClient`) was missing this.